# How to get Springs default Whitelabel Error Page when using Vaadin Flow

Tags: spring, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am currently setting up an admin UI for a service. How is it possible to send the default Spring Whitelabel Error Page instead of the Vaadin Message? The Problem is, that the Vaadin Page is blowing up my Log-Files.

So instead of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6hUE.jpg) i want
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9MUv.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is actually different. In Vaadin Flow application it is mandatory to have a view with empty, i.e. "" route. So you need to add `@Route("")` to your default view (or alternatively add `@RouteAlias("")` to it, if it has some other route too).

For other routes not defined by your application, Vaadin shows error view defined in `RouteNotFoundError` class. You can extend that class to customize your own error view to be shown on routes that are not found.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I dont really understand how to avoid sending a whole HTML page as  a Respononse, and instead send something like
{"timestamp":1548955929501,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found","path":"/abc"}